# Did Enoch resume his life in another sphere (world)?

Tags: genesis, hebrews

Enoch son of Jared in Genesis 5:21-24 (NIV):

> 21. When Enoch had lived 65 years, he became the father of Methuselah.
> 22. And after he became the father of Methuselah, Enoch walked with God 300 years and had other sons and daughters.
> 23. Altogether, Enoch lived 365 years.
> 24. Enoch walked with God; **then he was no more, because God took him away.**

The question is:

- Does "then he was no more, because God took him away" mean that He resumed his life in another sphere (world)?

Comment: What do you mean by "another sphere"?

Comment: @curiousdannii It could be speculated that Enoch continued to live a normal human life on another (appropriately provisioned) planet in another solar system : is what I assume is being asked.

Comment: @Nigel That's what I guessed too, but that requires bringing a whole load of assumptions to the text.

Comment: @curiousdannii . . .  indeed. Which _metathesis_ does not warrant.

Comment: @NigelJ if you are to remain consistent with Biblical cosmology it’s not another planet but crossed over beyond the firmament.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo I only commented on what is speculated. It is not what I would, myself, express. Your point is definitely taken. Thank you.

Comment: The two who "walked with God" (Noah & Enoch) had their lives saved. Noah's was temporarily as he survived the flood here. Enoch's was saved permanently but God took him away.  Where God took Enoch you can only speculate.

Comment: @ John Martin, yep that is correct what you say ( Where God took Enoch you can only speculate.) That's why i chose to vote to close this question.I do not think it is good practice on this site to answer this sort of question as there is no answer to it.

Comment: @Bagpipes I am not asking: where had Enoch been taken? I am asking: is he alive in another world?. The answer is yes or no!

Comment: @Salah Enoch was taken to Eden, there he **walked with** God, it does not say **walked before** but **with** God, God **sits** in heaven and the only place were God walks with man is in Eden and there Enoch were for 300 years from the age of 65 to the age of 365 then he died.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only other information available to us about the matter is in the description of Enoch's being taken in Hebrews 11:5 where the word *metathesis* is used which the KJV renders as 'translated'.

The Greek word occurs only three times in scripture.

Thayer says the word means a transposition, a change or an exchange.

'*Metathesis*' is used again in Hebrews 12:27 where the 'removing of the those things that are shaken' is reported, whilst other things remain.

And it is used a further time in Hebrews, in 7:12, where the removal of the first priesthood is described that another Priesthood may pertain.

The examination of these two other places would lead one to an understanding that the word *metathesis* conveys the removal of something, that something else may take its place. It does not give any indication of what occurs thereafter to the removed item.

The word, in its use by the same author in these two other places *focuses on what remains after the removal.*

The KJV translators have perhaps attempted a prediction by saying 'translated'. This is an archaic use of the English word 'translate' which is here used in an engineering sense where something is transposed, that is to say it is lifted up, kept in its orientation, then placed down again in another setting.

But the Greek word does not convey that.

Enoch was removed because of what was about to take place on earth. Once removed, his place was overrun by evil. God took him away before the evil completely swamped the whole earth.

Thereafter, the evil increased. Up to the point where all flesh must be removed from earth, so great was the wickedness and violence.

It can only be speculative to consider what happened to Enoch. What we on earth must focus upon is what occurred on earth after Enoch was removed.

Comment: Is the same word used in the LXX of Gen 5:24? I can't check on my phone sorry.

Comment: @curiousdannii   Yes, the same